# How to play raw pcm 16 bit data using audio toolbox in iphone

Tags: iphone, audiotoolbox

I am trying to play raw pcm data in iPhone using **Audio ToolBox** framework. I have tried to manage the callback system but the final output is not correct.

So, I am looking for some sample or example to play raw pcm 16 bit audio chunks. I first decode the audio chunks and all I get is raw 16 bit (short*) pcm data. Any help will be greatful.

Thanks.

Comment: Post some code of yours?

Comment: I have followed http://code.google.com/p/ffmpeg4iphone/source/browse/trunk/Player.m reference code.